# Applying Benders decomposition in CPLEX Studio IDE

Tags: optimization, cplex, decomposition

How to use Benders decomposition in Cplex Studio IDE?

(In Cplex documentation, they just speak about implementation of Benders in APIs)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using an old version. But in CPLEX 12.8 you may import in the IDE and use:

```
CPLEX_Studio128\opl\examples\opl\benders
```